# Get all public github repositories with pagination

Tags: github, github-api

I want to get all public Github repositories (api.github.com/repositories) with pagination (for example, get it by 10 repos). I tried https://api.github.com/repositories?page=2&per_page=10, but it's works only on search, but doesn't work on all public repos. How To get all public repos with pagination?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the Github API documentation, see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories.

The pagination is done by using the `since` URL parameter instead of `page`, the value of `since` is the numerical id of the last repository that you already have seen.
If you omit the `since` parameter the response will return a list of repositories, the first repo has id `1`. To get the next page you add `?since=369` to the next request (`369` is the last id that I get when requesting the first page).

For convenience the responses also includes the `Link` header which contains a ready-made URL to the next page.