# Unable to paginate github repository statistics

Tags: rest, pagination, github-api

I'm trying to paginate the repository statistics for a github repository using the REST API v3. Here's what I'm using:

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors`

An example URL: https://api.github.com/repos/shreyas1599/Movie-Rating-bot/stats/contributors?page=2&per_page=5

Pagination does not seem to work and returns the same result for all pages. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Per this: [Get all public github repositories with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925185/get-all-public-github-repositories-with-pagination) I tried using `since`. Unfortunately it uses the repository id. I tried using the id of `author` but that doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: met the same problem here